# SQLite Android - how to select or check for a row

Tags: android, sqlite

So im new to working with SQlite and android, I have started out by creating a DataBase Manager class as seen below:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    static final String dbName ="LCInstore";

    static final String allIcons = "Icons";
    static final String homeIcons = "HomeScreenIcons";

    static final String colIconID = "IconID";
    static final String colID = "ID";
    static final String colImage = "IconImage";
    static final String colLabel = "IconLabel";
    static final String colName = "IconName";

    public DataBaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 0); // starting value is zero must change on upgrades
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Create Icon Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT CREATED"+ allIcons +"" +
                "("+colIconID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    colName + " TEXT," +
                    colImage + " TEXT," +
                    colLabel + "TEXT)");

        // Create HomeScreen Icons Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + homeIcons+"" +
                "("+colID+" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+colID+") REFERENCES" +
                        ""+allIcons+" ("+colIconID+"));");

         InsertIcons(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+allIcons);

    }

    private void InsertIcons(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colIconID, 1);
           cv.put(colName, "Icon1");
           cv.put(colImage, "icon_one");
           cv.put(colLabel, "ONE");
           db.insert(allIcons, colIconID, cv);

           cv.put(colIconID, 2);
           cv.put(colName, "Icon2");
           cv.put(colImage, "icon_two");
           cv.put(colLabel, "TWO");
           db.insert(allIcons, colIconID, cv);

           cv.put(colIconID, 3);
           cv.put(colName, "Icon3");
           cv.put(colImage, "icon_three");
           cv.put(colLabel, "THREE");
           db.insert(allIcons, colIconID, cv);

           db.close();
    }

    public void AddHomeScreenIcon(int id){

   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
   //HELP
   // Need to check if id already exists in colID of homeIcons TABLE
   // and if it doesn't do this
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ homeIcons +" where colID = " +id, null);
   int numFound = c.getCount();

   if(numFound<1){
       ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
       cv.put(colID, id);
       db.insert(homeIcons, colID, cv);
   }

   // else do nothing

 }

public void DeleteHomeScreenIcon (int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(homeIcons, "id = " +id, null);
    // HELP
    //Need to  find row of homeIcons table that matches id and delete it
    db.close();
}


}
```

you'll notice in my last two methods i have put //HELP those comments are what i need help with..

ANONTHER QUESTION:  if later i update my app, i assume it will not get rid of the DB or make any changes to it..  but how does the onUpgrade get called.. and how do i control that in upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for could be solved in SQL with `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO` and `DELETE FROM`.

*Update*: The SQL would be something like `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO homeIcons VALUES(colID, cv)` and `DELETE FROM homeIcons WHERE ID=?`

Comment: hmm this looks like the simplest approach..  but i guess i am still unclear as to write it..

Comment: I updated the answer with example SQL that should work in SQLite

Comment: I don't see your update?  is there a difference between using 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO homeIcons VALUES(colID, cv) and DELETE FROM homeIcons WHERE ID=?' and the way i am doing it now?  see updated code?

Comment: It doesn't differ, they are more or less the same. Though your code could be made more efficient with using `select count(*) from ...` in addHomeScreenIcon, instead of selecting everything and then counting the rows...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 3/29/2014 fixed typo (= should be + in first snippit)

To determine if they exist you need a cursor with the activity's context, then:

```
//Querying TABLE_NAME for ID in the colId column
cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                  new String[] {ALL, My, COLUMN, NAMES, EG, colId },
                  colId + " = ? ",
                  new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{ /* IT EXISTS! */ }
```

To delete is equally easy

```
db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
boolean success = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, 
            colID + " = ?", 
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)})>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For queries, if you find `db.query()` to be too tedious and complex, an alternative would be to use  `db.rawQuery()` instead.

For the first HELP you could try:
`Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from homeIcons where colID = " + id, null);`
then use `int numRows = cur.getCount();` to retrieve the number of columns returned.

For deletes:
`int err = db.delete("homeIcons", "id = " + id, null);`

For operations that are not queries, it is always suggested to check the return value for failures.

Comment: couple questions..  for the the deletes:  why not just  - db.delete(homeIcons, "id = " +id, null);  whats the "int err =" part?
also whats the difference  between the whereClause and whereArgs?

Comment: From the text, they seem to be correct. But you'll have to run it to be sure. The whereargs is used to substitute any "?" you may have in whereclause. The err is in complement with the last line: For operations that are not queries, it is always suggested to check the return value for failures.